# Pass additional data while registering user using Djoser and Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Djoser(https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser) along with Django Rest Framework. I'm using the default /register/ endpoint provided by Djoser. Now, I want to pass additional information at the time of registering a user. Say for example the referral code (to see where the user came from). I think I need to implement this logic in create_user method of my UserManager class.

Here is my MyUserManager:

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, name, email, referrer_code="", password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        print "referrercode" + referrer_code
        referrer = 0
        if (referrer_code != ""):
            try:
                referrer = MyUser.objects.filter(referral_code=referrer_code).first().id
            except:
                referrer = 0
        user = self.model(
            name=name,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            referrer=referrer,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Here, `referrer_code` is what I want to pass as a part of the POST request.

Here is my MyUser model:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    referrer = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', ]
```

This is what it says on the djoser documentation page:

> Use this endpoint to register new user. Your user model manager should
>   implement create_user method and have USERNAME_FIELD and
>   REQUIRED_FIELDS fields.

However, in my case, referrer_code is not a field of the user that is being registered, it is a field of the user who referred the new one. So I don't think including referral_code as a required field would help.

Comment: can't you pass it as a url parameter? I am not sure it would end up in `self.request.query_params` as it does when it's a GET request.

Comment: Since I'm using the default /register/ endpoint provided by djoser, I don't have access to the view. I am anyeays going to pass the parameter in the POST request, but I don't have a place to access it.

Comment: Did you include only a new serializer and specify that in DJOSER object in `settings.py` od did you have to also create new URL and View for the custom registration to work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

May or may not be helpful and this is old, but it's still unanswered so here goes.

Came across a similar issue where I was using a custom User model (extending AbstractBaseUser), and despite anything I did on the serializer, the DRF would only show the default fields - I think name, email, and password.

I'd gone through the docs and done everything specified, including specifying the serializer in `settings.py` as they do in the example in the docs: 
`'user': 'myapp.serializers.SpecialUserSerializer'`, but still no dice.

Turns out that you need a serializer for each endpoint. I'd expected that you'd define a `User` serializer, and the registration endpoint would grab from that. Instead, you need a `user_registration` endpoint that defines just the stuff necessary for registration. These are all the defaults, each of which you'd have to override as applicable:

```
{
    'activation': 'djoser.serializers.ActivationSerializer',
    'login': 'djoser.serializers.LoginSerializer',
    'password_reset': 'djoser.serializers.PasswordResetSerializer',
    'password_reset_confirm':     'djoser.serializers.PasswordResetConfirmSerializer',
    'password_reset_confirm_retype': 'djoser.serializers.PasswordResetConfirmRetypeSerializer',
    'set_password': 'djoser.serializers.SetPasswordSerializer',
    'set_password_retype': 'djoser.serializers.SetPasswordRetypeSerializer',
    'set_username': 'djoser.serializers.SetUsernameSerializer',
    'set_username_retype': 'djoser.serializers.SetUsernameRetypeSerializer',
    'user_registration': 'djoser.serializers.UserRegistrationSerializer',
    'user': 'djoser.serializers.UserSerializer',
    'token': 'djoser.serializers.TokenSerializer',
}
```

So in my case, I put this in `settings.py`:

```
DJOSER = {
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_registration': 'account.serializers.UserSerializer',
    },
}
```

and the endpoing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/register/` is now showing the fields I wanted it to. Hope that helps someone else!

Comment: This is the only answer. It should be accepted answer

Comment: I did this its working but now i am getting error that username field is required , how to cope up with that ?

Comment: Could you please post an example of the User Registration custom serializer that you are using in order to show how the serialization with the different fields happens?