# Register User with custom fields in Djoser and Rest Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use the "register" endpoint from [Djoser](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser). It works properly, but I need more fields than just "username", "email" and "password".
I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789103/pass-additional-data-while-registering-user-using-djoser-and-django-rest-framewo) and indeed I can see the fields I wanted (in the browsable API). But when I try to post it, I get this error

> ImproperlyConfigured at /account/register/ Could not resolve URL
>   for hyperlinked relationship using view name "user-detail". You may
>   have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly
>   configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

And I don't have idea what's going wrong.

My models.py looks so:

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    birthday = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

the serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from users.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'email', 'name', 'last_name', 'birthday', 'password')
```

my views.py

```
from users.models import User
from users.serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

and in the settings.py I added:

```
DJOSER = {
    ...
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_registration': 'users.serializers.UserSerializer',
    },
}
```

**EDIT**

App/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from users import views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view

# Create a router and register our viewsets with it.
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

schema_view = get_schema_view(title='Pastebin API')

# The API URLs are now determined automatically by the router.
# Additionally, we include the login URLs for the browsable API.

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url('^schema/$', schema_view),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

api/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework_jwt import views as jwt_views
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^account/', include('djoser.urls')),
    url(r'^auth/login/', jwt_views.obtain_jwt_token, name='auth'),
]
```

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Try renaming your 'User' model to something like 'ExtendedUser' and include to it's fields a OneToOne relation with django.contrib.aut.models.User model. If it works well, I'll explain why.

Comment: Also, I don't see HyperlinkedIdentityField in serializer...

Comment: Hi Kid, thank you. 
I'm new in Django and the Rest Framework. What do you mean with ```include to it's fields a OneToOne relation with django.contrib.auth.models.User model``` ?
I looked [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/) but I don't get how should I do it.

Comment: Disregard that for a moment, I think I know the real reason. Can you show me your `urls.py` file and `urlpatterns` entry that maps to `UserViewSet`?

Comment: Done. Thank you again. Maybe there's the problem. I think I merge too much in the urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is clear: Django cannot resolve URL by `user-detail` name. It tries to do so because you've made an extended serializer from `serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer` with a `url` field, which should contain a link to your specific user object.

The problem I see is that your main `urls.py` does not include `api` urls, and they all duplicated and wired up kinda strange. I would rewrite it as follows (assuming you also have `user` app):

**Root `urls.py`:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view
from rest_framework_jwt import views as jwt_views

schema_view = get_schema_view(title='Pastebin API')

urlpatterns = [
    url('^schema/$', schema_view),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^user/', include('user.urls')),
    url(r'^account/', include('djoser.urls')),
    # Not sure if you need both:
    url(r'^auth/login/', jwt_views.obtain_jwt_token, name='auth'),
    url(
        r'^api-auth/',
        include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

**User app `urls.py`:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from .views import UserViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

And I'm not sure why you need another app called `api` though.

If it doesn't help, try examining this article on [namespacing the router](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#using-include-with-routers).

Comment: Yeah, pretty well. I need to learn a bit more about it, but it worked. :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

You can create a Custom User in **django 2.0** using **djoser** by inheriting with **AbstractUser**, which creates a new user model with respect to your app like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    FUNCTION = 1
    VIEWER = 2
    TECHNICIAN = 3
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (FUNCTION, 'Functional'),
        (VIEWER, 'Viewer'),
        (TECHNICIAN, 'Technician'),
    )
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email", "role"]
```

and then defined user new User class in ***settings.py***:
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_name.User'

Please note that here I have defined my REQUIRED_FIELDS. So when I use the djoser **API /me/**, it will give me all the required fields.

Comment: is it possible to add as required fields, fields that are part of a model which is related to the user model? (E.g. adding the user address on signup which is its own separate model; and create at registration the `Address` table identity connected with FK to the user who just singed up)